# Change an Array search function to return more then one result

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I modified a function that searches through an array to return the parent item if a value is found within the array. It works fine for returning the first item found but I want it to return all the items found. I presume it's because i'm returning the array right away but i'm not sure how to change it to make it "go back" and return multiple finds.

Function:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if ($item === $needle || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item))) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning right away, just append $item in an array. Replace `return false` with `return $your_array` (the one containing your items). $your_array will therefore contain every item matching your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you return from a function, execution is complete.  I'm not sure what the purpose of returning one arbitrary value serves, when you already know that it is equivalent to $needle.  Seems like it should simply return true.  Let's say you did modify the function to add a $matches array that you stored matches in.  What would the value of that be to you to end up with an array that had 3 "foo" elements in it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code I ended up with to fix it. Thanks for the quick answers :)

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack) {
   $array = array(); 
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if ($item === $needle || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item))) {
            array_push($array,$item);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```